# UnboundLocalError: local 'category' variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-views

im learning django by doing small web app that im following from http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/models_templates.html now chapter 6

views.py

```
   category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]  
   def index(request):
   context = RequestContext(request)
   global category_list
   context_dict = {'categories': category_list}

    for category in category_list:
    category.url = category.name.replace(' ', '_')
    return render_to_response('rango/index.html', context_dict, context)


    def category(request, category_name_url):

     context = RequestContext(request)
     category_name = category_name_url.replace('_', ' ')
     context_dict = {'category_name': category_name}

try:

    category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
    pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)
    context_dict['pages'] = pages
    context_dict['category'] = category

except Category.DoesNotExist:
    pass

return render_to_response('rango/category.html', context_dict, context)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/$', views.category, name='category'),) 
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://'localhost:8080'/rango/catgeory/python/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rango')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\Documents\tango\rango\views.py" in catgeory
  34.     except  catgeory.DoesNotExist:  

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /rango/catgeory/python/
Exception Value: local variable 'catgeory' referenced before assignment
```

actually `category_name_url=u'python'` which is good for python but I'm not sure about `u` before the value and im working on eclipse

Comment: Can you please paste, the error in your post?

Comment: The code posted here won't throw that exception. What are you 100% certain that you are running this code and not something else? What is the *full* traceback?

Answer (score 1):

That traceback does not match your code. The view code says `Category.DoesNotExist` while the traceback shows `category.DoesNotExist`. The former works because the class `Category` is defined. The latter will not work because `category` doesn't yet exist when the exception is raised by `Category.objects.get()`.

If the view code above is accurate then you're having some other problem that's causing stale code to be executed.